# Can a manifold that contains a flat part be analytic?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

If a manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a flat part where it is locally given by the surface of a hyperplane, and the rest is curved, could this be an analytic manifold? [In other words](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_manifold), is it possible for such a manifold to be differentiable with analytic transition maps?

Comment: In a word, _no_.

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "analytic manifold". The manifold itself may have an analytic structure, but the embedding into $\Bbb R^n$ (or anywhere else) cannot be analytic. For example, the sphere is analytic and embeds as a cube into $\Bbb R^3$, but not analytically.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have clarified what I mean by “analytic manifold” in my description following your comment. I follow the definition in the Wikipedia article for “analytic manifold”. The main difficulty for me is that unlike a real function with which I can actually work out the Taylor series to examine if it agrees with the function at any given point, the transition maps of a manifold are always assumed to be existent but never explicit. To show whether the given manifold is analytic, I don’t suppose one is expected to construct the transition maps first?

Comment: As Paul notes, there is a distinction between a _manifold with analytic transition functions_ (such as Cartesian space itself, with one chart) and such a manifold _analytically embedded_ in a Cartesian space (i.e., an _analytic hypersurface_). My first comment refers to the latter situation. It _is_ possible to _smoothly_ (and explicitly) embed an analytic manifold so that part of it is a flat hypersurface, but I think it's not unfair to say that without explicitly specifying intent, that interpretation would not naturally come to mind. ;)

Comment: It's worth noting that any smooth manifold is an analytic manifold. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8789/can-every-manifold-be-given-an-analytic-structure

Comment: In other words, the analyticity assumption, as stated, is useless, one can as well require the manifold to be smoothable. The meaningful assumption is that the manifold is real-analytic as a subset of $R^n$.

Comment: @Deane Thanks for the pointer. I did read this page yesterday, but wasn’t entirely sure about the notion of being given an analytic structure. Comments by Paul and Andrew helped a lot in this regard. So now I know that Whitney’s result mentioned therein applies.

Answer (score 3):

That is the "analytic structure" I was referring to. Let me step down 1 dimension in my example. The circle is analytic and embeddable in $\Bbb R^2$ as a square. It is the embedding that fails to be analytic (or even differentiable), not the circle itself.

To show that a manifold is analytic, you have show the existence of a covering by charts whose transition maps are all analytic. For the circle two charts are sufficient: stereographic projection from the north and south poles onto the equatorial line. That is, with $S^1$ taken as the unit circle in the plane, draw a line from $(0,1)$ through a point $p = (u,v) \in S^1$ and the coordinate $x$ where this line intersects the $x$-axis defines a chart on $S^1\setminus (0,1)$:
$$(u,v) \mapsto \frac u{1-v}=\text{sgn}(u)\sqrt{\frac{1+v}{1-v}}$$
Using $(0,-1)$ as the pole instead gives the chart
$$(u,v) \mapsto \frac u{1+v}=\text{sgn}(u)\sqrt{\frac{1-v}{1+v}}$$
The transition function between these two charts is $t \mapsto \frac 1t$.

Since this is analytic everywhere it is defined, the circle is an analytic manifold.

Comment: Thank you for showing the analyticity of a circle. However, the original question asks about a manifold with a flat part. In the circle example, it would be something like part of the top arc replaced with a straight line segment (and possibly the resulting corners smoothed out).

Comment: The "flat part" is not something of the manifold itself. That is a property of how the manifold is embedded into $\Bbb R^n$. And that embedding, as Andrew D. Hwang stated right from the first, and as I have re-iterated, cannot be analytic. At the boundary between the flat and unflat portions, the Taylor series of the extrinsic curvature has to be $0$ to accommodate the flat portion. But that means it is $0$ everywhere in the radius of convergence, contradicting that the point is on the boundary. Your later comment was about intrinsic properties, not the embedding.

Comment: But as Deane points out, every $C^\infty$ manifold admits an analytic atlas. Further, that atlas is unique (see Greg Kuperberg's answer in the thread Deane links to). Which means that "analytic manifolds" and "$C^\infty$ manifolds" are the same thing. Although it isn't completely clear from what I've seen in that thread, I'm pretty sure they are also the same thing as "$C^1$ manifolds". (All $C^1$ manifolds admit a $C^\infty$ atlas, but is it unique?) It is just a matter of how restrictive you make the atlas.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, such $C^\infty$ structure  is unique up to an isomorphism. You just use approximation of a $C^1$ diffeomorphism by smooth maps and then check that approximants are again diffeomorphisms.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Your comments and Andrew D. Hwang's on the original question indeed made the distinction very clear in my mind. And indeed, I have always asked about the intrinsic property. But I borrowed the language of embedding to describe what kind of manifold is in question. I had previously heard that the n-sphere is an analytic manifold, but was unsure whether a different "shape" seen from its embedding in $\mathbb{R}^n$ would have an impact on the analyticity. So it was important for me to see that the particular shape, not an n-sphere, can be an analytic manifold.

Comment: @PaulSinclair While the link provided by Deano answered my question in the positive, you posted an answer with a "constructivist" approach, that is you explicitly provided the charts and the transition map. It's just that it was about the 1-sphere instead of the shape I asked for. That's why I felt it did not directly address my question, and so made the first comment to your answer.